# Can I install Node.js on Android either rooted or not?

Tags: android, c++, node.js, android-ndk, libc++

I'm Trying to install node on android

I have tried:

- Complete Linux rooted with Ubuntu and debian 4. Always getting troubles with repositories not followed and/or troubleshots
- Linux deploy with one/two distros
- Gnuroot with fedora remix
  Having troubles with GCC not installés ans yum troubleshots probably due to repositories.

I have some questions:

- Has anyone tried using Debian without Root and installing node?
- Does anyone know if it might work on Ubuntu touch?
- There is a post on how to compile node but I don't understand why jxcore is mentioned in comments and why there is an Android version of jxcore when it's not an APK?

Comment: Since you asked this question many approaches no longer work. I created a recent investigation of some options: [Viable options to running NodeJS on Android (Aug 2017)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45649995/8295283). And yes, this is possible without rooting (even an install via Termux is).

Answer (score 1):

It [is possible] 1 to get node on Android. In fact, in 2020, at the time of this writing, there is an app available through Google Play store. The app called Dory node js. It comes with not only node, but also npm, password encrypted dev server (completely set up, you need only flip a switch in the context menu - and set up the password, especially if port forwarding).

There are a few minor issues, due to Android's security policies (namely file access.) Also I read in the reviews that the version is outdated. But, as it comes with npm,  an issue.

Keep in mind, I have no idea who created this app. I researched it myself for about 30 minutes, and I saw a lot of decent reviews, with nothing that scared me. With that said, as I don't know the source, I am not recommending it, just letting everyone know it's there. As always you need to do the research, especially as you'll have to give the app the read write permission for npm.

Comment: Link didn't work for Google Play. You can search Dory node on the Play Store. Alternatively, the developer's account name is tempeage.io

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter rooted or not.

Node.JS doesn't support mobile targets primarily. JXcore is a fork of node.js that works on both desktop and mobile OSes. JXcore's primary target is mobile, you can find JXcore Android release binaries from [this link](http://jxcore.com/downloads)

Comment: Unfortunately JXCore is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

try termux, its like linux for android. works with/without root!